# Verb for screencast (presented, instructed, performed)

Tags: word-choice

I recently taught in a class and captured a video from my screen (aka screencast)

Now I want to add a text to introduce myself (who was the teacher)

Which verb to use? Perform(ed), tutor(ed), instruct(ed)?

Comment: That would depend on how do you wish to frame your sentence. Provide an example sentence and leave a blank where you'd like the verb to go.

Comment: @vickyace it's not a complete sentence: "Instructed by MYNAME"

Comment: **Instructor: YOUR NAME** should do it.

Comment: @vickyace thanks, post it as answer?

Comment: That is alright. There are many possibilities here. Happy to help.

Comment: @vickyace i mean could you please post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are several possibilities:

**Instructor: Mr X**

**Mentor/tutor/pedagog: Mr X**